# What is the meaning of "Tabako-wa goenryo kudasai"

Tags: translation, words

From what I understand, this means "Please refrain from smoking". However, I cannot find what "goenryo" means by looking it up in the dictionary.

Can someone help me by explaining what it means?

Comment: "ny" is not a valid syllable in Japanese. No wonder you could not find it in the dictionary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The word is 御遠慮 (go-enryo)

遠慮する: to  refrain from
http://jisho.org/search/%E9%81%A0%E6%85%AE

御: honorific/polite prefix
http://jisho.org/search/%E5%BE%A1

Answer (score 5):

I suppose it is Tabako-wa goenryo kudasai(タバコはご遠慮ください).
That means:

> **Refrain from** smoking.

遠慮 means **refrain from**. Similar to 控える. Commonly used in instructions.

Answer (score 4):

"go" is to be polite and is not part of the word. The word is enryo.
タバコはご「遠慮」ください。